# Verilog using @ with conditional if

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

Hello I have a question about Verilog grammar.

I am aware that @ is used with always usually.

but I want to do some action when a variable changes its value.

for example, I want to find out if switch is changing.

So, I tried if (@ posedge switch or negedge  switch)

But this made an error.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us your error and if this is for synthesizable code

Comment: @close-voters In what way is this question less about programming than most other Verilog questions? And if you think that HDLs have nothing to do with programming, how come I find myself teaching, Factory Pattern, Subscriber Pattern, Singleton Pattern?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor , at least two of the close votes are for insufficient information; hence my up-vote on dave_59's comment. A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be useful.

Comment: Using another always was not what I intended since one variable can be changed in only one always statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a synchronous design (And you want to do that ;), you have to change state of all your signal on one clock edge (generally rising).

Then to detect switch edge you have to save state of switch value and compare it with actual on rising edge of clock.

```
always @(posedge clock)
   begin

       if (switch_old != switch)
             switch_edge <= 1'b1;
       else
             switch_edge <= 1'b0;

       switch_old  <= switch;
   end
```

You can't do what you ask in a synchronous design, then it can't be syntesizable reasonably.